# AppSDK 2.0: Where do I go to access?

Tags: rally

I'm noting references to a 2.0 version of Rally's AppSDK in replies to the following:

[Remove html markup from Rally description field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442084/remove-html-markup-from-rally-description-field)

[Is there a way to refresh the list in an object dropdown using new query conditions ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464699/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-the-list-in-an-object-dropdown-using-new-query-conditi)

I'm not seeing any references to AppSDK 2.0 either in the WSAPI documentation:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice

or on the Developer portal:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/

Is this toolkit officially available? If so, how can I access and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of the [Developer Portal](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/) you can find a link at the bottom that says "App SDK 2.0 Preview" that will take you there.

If you want a direct link to our current preview version of the SDK you can find it [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/).

This link may not work forever as it is a preview version but in the future you will be able to find our current SDKs from the Developer Portal.

Comment: Thanks! Must have glossed over that link in my scan through the Developer Portal. Look forward to trying out the new toolkit - watch for questions to come ;-)

Comment: If you want to see some sample Apps from last weeks Hackathon you can checkout the GitHub organization we used for our projects.

https://github.com/RallyHackathon

Answer (score 1):

It is available, but its the App SDK, not a new Web services API.

The main Rally SDK doc has a link: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk